# Why does vetoIfFailing crash cruise control?

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol

I am having this weird issue with Cruise Control crashing, when I add the `vetoIfFailing` attribute to the [`buildstatus`](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#buildstatus) element.

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <project>
    <modificationset>
      <buildstatus>
```

This causes the entire machine to say `stopped` for all projects:

```
<buildstatus logdir="/mycruisedir/logs/myproject" vetoIfFailing="true" />
```

... but this works:

```
<buildstatus logdir="/mycruisedir/logs/myproject" />
```

So what is wrong with the `vetoIfFailing` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vetoIfFailing` attribute for the `buildstatus` element was only added in CruiseControl v2.8.0 [release notes](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=629858).

I was using an earlier version - should have checked this first.